# Why are movies still shot on film?

Tags: production, cinematography

Many modern big budget films such as [Star Wars: The Force Awakens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Star_Wars:_The_Force_Awakens), [Interstellar](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Interstellar_(film)) and even some TV shows such as [Breaking Bad](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Breaking_Bad) are still shot on film.

Directors such as Christopher Nolan and Quentin Tarantino have stated that they oppose digital cinematography due to the inferior image quality. Tarantino even saying that he thinks digital cinema is the ["death rattle"](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BON9Ksn1PqI) of the film industry.

What are the benefits of shooting on film? Pre-2010 it seems film may have had a technical edge, but with the advancing technology I cannot see any way in which film is still superior:

Modern digital cameras are smaller, lighter, cheaper, more flexible and offer a much higher dynamic range, frame rate and a similar or better resolution than their film counterparts. In addition, most films are edited and projected digitally at 2K or 4K which would remove any additional resolution you may gain from film. Even if a "film look" is desired it can be created in post production from digital footage and can look indistinguishable from real film.

Why do many directors and cinematographers still prefer film? I cannot find anything other than vague mentions of "better resolution" or "it just looks better".

Comment: [Related?](http://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/was-film-actually-better-than-digital-media/)

Comment: Many are shot digitally: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_films_shot_on_digital_video_prior_to_2015

Comment: @Walt...if not a dupe that one.

Comment: @Walt Seeing as I don't feel the need to re-write my answer, I'd agree that's a dupe :P

Comment: 35mm is about 5400 X 3600 pixels, so about 4k resolution. 70mm is about 16k pixels, so better than 4k. Plus, some directors like the "feel" of film better than digital.

Comment: I've heard ideas such as the flickering light of traditional film as the cells stream past the bulb making the experience more captivating.   Based on @zeta-band's point, we may have to wait until digital has the same or better resolution than film to determine if the greater "sensual" quality ascribed to film is merely romantic or has to do with the process itself.  (i.e. many purists still prefer vinyl or reel-to-reel over digital music, no matter the size of the digital file.)

Comment: Among the many advantages of film, the fact that you can keep the negatives in a metal box for 100 years and it will be preserved without any damage or associated cost is a tremendous advantage. A lot of digital data produced in the world will most likely disappear within the next 50 years by lack of time-resisting support or backup budget or skilled technicians.

Comment: @MicroMachine: Keeping film negatives in pristine condition is probably more expensive than maintaining digital data.  Film which sits neglected in a warehouse for 50 years, however, would more likely be at least somewhat usable than digital media which is likewise neglected.

Comment: @supercat How about 100-150 years? There are people successfully restoring films from the 1890s right now, all I was saying is that I'd love to see how one would restore a 100 year old hard drive or CD-Rom. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_rediscovered_films) [2](https://www.theguardian.com/film/2014/dec/11/bfi-and-bbc-restore-first-ever-british-science-fiction-movie) [3](http://www.telegraph.co.uk/films/2016/04/19/worlds-first-colour-film-unveiled/) - while reading these articles, keep in mind the astonishing progress film support went through over the past 100 years in durability.

Comment: @MicroMachine: Digital content is more likely than film to become completely unreadable in the absence of active maintenance.  On the other hand, analog film will degrade with time no matter how much effort one expends preserving it.  The best one can do is slow down such degradation.  Digital content can be kept in pristine form indefinitely, however, with a relatively modest amount of ongoing effort, and would be unlikely to be come unreadable absent negligence (or malfeasance) in its preservation.

Comment: First of all, copying old decaying film to new film stock will preserve 99% of the original negative's current information for another 100 years or so (check the links I gave, amazing results 100 years after...). Secondly, you might mix up "preserving" with "restoring". Sadly, we don't live in a world where everything that is filmed has a decent "preservation" or "restoration" budget attached to it (let alone a filming budget). Add to that, anything anyone puts on film can become a historic document after 100+ years, times gives it its worth, not the budget or script that came with it.