# How are movies shot on film cut and edited nowadays?

Tags: production, editing

Many movies are still shot on films. At the same time, computers can greatly facilitate editing. So I just wonder how the whole process is done. Is film digitized and edited on computers or is it literally cut and edited like in old good times?

Comment: Related, not sure on duplicate, https://movies.stackexchange.com/questions/34435/27264

Comment: @AJ Not a duplicate, the question you refer to is whether film is better than digital media whereas I'm asking how film is further processed in modern production.

Comment: Look at those answers on that question. See if any helps.

Comment: @AJ I've looked at them. They are mostly about film having better dynamic range while being more expensive and inconvenient to use. Still interesting information, thank you for the link.

Comment: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Film_editing#Film_editing_technology

Comment: @BCdotWEB If film gets digitized anyway, doesn't it compromise it's main advantage - great dynamic range?

Comment: @olegst That's not what it says there. It says the editing is done to produce a list of edits. This list could then be used to apply to the actual film stock. In any case, the movie will still get digitized anyway, since the vast majority of movie theaters don't have non-digital projectors anymore.

Comment: @BCdotWEB Is digitized film still better than shooting on a digital camera? I'm just trying to understand why they still use film if digitizing equipment actually is the same digital camera with poorer dynamic range.

Answer (score 2):

I can answer this as least as far back as Star Wars Episode VII. The movie was shot on film, and the film was digitized as reels were filled up (they didn't save it all and wait until all of filming was finished) then the film rolls were treated and archived to help preserve them. From there on out, all editing and work was done digitally.

If one was lucky to ever tour Lucasfilm in San Francisco, you would find lots of old film editing equipment on display in the hallways -- they don't use it anymore.